# Does a bound on a solution to an ODE allow for it to be defined over all $t \in \Bbb R$?

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$ x^{(n)}(t) = f(t, x, x^{(1)}, \dots, x^{(n-1)})$$

Much of the books I have read through talk about results for very loose conditions on $f$.  My first question is are there any references which look strictly at the case for $f$ smooth in all its variables?  I am finding it hard to filter through the results for nice $f$ and those for $f$ which can be a lot nastier and not of importance to me.

Question I am after a solution for in particular:

Suppose I have the problem above where $f$ is smooth in all its variables and an initial value $I = (t_0, x(t_0), \dots, x^{(n-1)}(t_0))$.  Suppose further that for this initial value, I know that for any solution $x(t)$, $\|x(t)\| \leq g_I(t)$ where $g_I$ is a smooth function defined over all of $\Bbb R$.  Can I then conclude there is a unique solution to the IVP given by $I$ defined over all of $\Bbb R$ since $x(t)$ does not diverge in finite time (and there is local existence around $t_0$)?  Or do I require more, that all of the derivatives $$\| (x(t), x^{(1)}(t), \dots, x^{(n-1)}(t)) \| \leq h_I(t)$$

Thanks

Comment: Sufficient conditions are that (under some mild technical assumptions on $f$) $(x(t),x^1(t),\dots,x^{n-1}(t))$ belongs to a compact set for all $t\geq t_0$. Alternatively, $f$ being differentiable and its derivative being bounded is sufficient as well. See Theorems 3.2 and 3.3 in [here](http://www.amazon.com/Nonlinear-Systems-3rd-Hassan-Khalil/dp/0130673897). However, you are probably looking for considerably weaker conditions than these (which I'd be very interested in knowing as well).

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Yeah, rather than being in a bounded set, I would like to contain them in a set of growing but known and extendible size.  It seems like to me this should be true since for any finite $T$, I can place a bound on the values using $h_I$ restricted to that $T$ and so I can extend it at least up to time $T$.  But since $T$ is arbitrary, I should be able to do this indefinitely

Comment: Hm.  I think that looks a bit like a valid proof.  I'll try get a copy of that book so I can see the details a bit closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comments - you are right:

Consider the initial value problem

$$\dot{z}=g(t,z),\quad\quad z(t_0)=z_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$$

where $g$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{C}^1$. Note that you can re-write your problem as the above by setting

$$z:=(x,x^1,\dots,x^{n-1}),\quad\quad z_0=I, \quad\quad g_i(t,z):=z_{i+1}\quad\forall i\neq n,$$
$$g_n(t,z):=f(t,xz)$$

Then, Khalil states (in p. 93)

"There is a maximum interval $[t_0,T)$ where the unique solutions starting at $(t_0,z_0)$ exists. If $T<\infty$ then as $t\rightarrow T$, the solution leaves any compact set over which $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $x$".

Since $g$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, it is Lipschitz at any point (that is, there is a neighbourhood around the point such that the Lipschitz condition holds), thus the Lipschitz condition holds over any compact set (just cover the set, extract a finite sub cover and pick the maximum Lipschitz constant). Then, by contradiction, you can conclude that $x$ exists over $[t_0,\infty)$.

Remark: He doesn't prove in the book what he says in the quote. He says a proof for the phrase bit can be found in section 8.5 of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123495504) or in section 2.3 of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008SM36G2) - I suspect this is pretty standard and can be found in many other places as well. The rest he leaves as an exercise. If you'd like, let me know and I can (attempt) to prove.

Comment: Thanks for the help,  I ended up at the same conclusion too, I'll leave the question for a day to see if the question garners any additional interest.  If nothing happens by then, I will accept this answer and award you the bounty :)

Comment: Glad to - give it some time, with a bit of luck someone will post a more interesting answer.